# How to get process name (or process) from PID in lisp?

Tags: process

I would like to check if my shell is running ssh or not by checking the process name.  I tried to get the process name by:

```
(let* ((proc (get-process "shell")) (proc-child-id (process-running-child-p proc)))
  (if proc-child-id
     (message (process-name proc-child-id))))
```

But it doesn't work because `process-name` expect a PROCESS instead of PID.  How can I get PROCESS from PID?  Or how can I get the child process name directly?

Comment: Try to check if `(alist-get 'comm (process-attributes PID))` returns `ssh`. BTW, the ssh process is created by shell, not Emacs, so it is not an Emacs subprocess so `process-name` etc doesn't make sense, I guess. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Processes.html

Comment: Somehow it always returns `nil`..  Thanks for your reply anyway~

Comment: This is my guess: "In some environments, process-attributes is unimplimented and always returns nil." https://notmuchmail.org/pipermail/notmuch/2014/016796.html

I'm using Emacs.app from http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: If so, you can try `ps -o comm= -p PID`. `process-attributes` doesn't return nil from here, I am using latest Emacs (built from git repo last month) on Mac.

Comment: Oh.. I can run the `ps` command in terminal, but `(shell-command "ps -o comm= -p 78058")` return 0 in Emacs.  I think there maybe some permission issue for my Emacs..

Comment: `shell-command` returns exit status. `shell-command-to-string` returns the output.

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much!